# How to get data with json file

Tags: angular, json-server

I want to get "results" into "page:1" with json server url because my code wants just "results" data, how can I do it?

Here is my json file

```
{
"page": 1,
"results": [
{
"title": "Mortal Kombat"
             
}
],
"total_pages": 438,
"total_results": 8742
}
```

Comment: Do you mean => response.results.title   ??

Comment: @elhamdabiri no, I can't access the results because "page" blocking results, so when I am delete "page" working but I don't want to delete it

Comment: Do you have json file in your code or you're getting the response from particular URL?

Comment: @KartikDolas from url

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it will work or not I am trying to debug by considering json typicode as anology but if page:1 is primary parameter and `www.sampleUrl.com` is generalized URL to get the whole result then try to hit `wwww.sampleUrl.com/:pageId` i.e. `www.sampleUrl.com/1` here. Please let me know if it works or else I'll need json url if it's public url.